# self join sql query with different conditions

Tags: sql, join

I have a simple kpi table with id, name, value per below

```
id    name    value
-------------------
1     kpi1      100
1     kpi1      100
1     kpi1      100
1     kpi1      100
1     kpi2      100
1     kpi2      0
1     kpi2      100
1     kpi2      100
2     kpi1      100
2     kpi1      0
2     kpi1      0
2     kpi1      0
2     kpi2      100
2     kpi2      100
2     kpi2      100
2     kpi2      100
```

I want the query to return a distinct 1 line per id and per name for the value = 0 first if exists otherwise the value = 100.

```
id    name    value
-------------------
1     kpi1      100
1     kpi2      0
2     kpi1      0
2     kpi2      100
```

I tried using joins without really knowing if it is the right way because I do not how to add the condition to select a kpi with a value at 0 first and if it does exist a value at 100.

```
select * from (select * from kpi where value='0') a inner join (select * from kpi where value='100') b on a.id=b.id
```

Hope I am clear enough I spent the day figuring out joins without success. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hR9NeQgTFikMjTjCKsqxP4/0).

```
  select
    id,
    name,
    value
from
(
    select
        id,
        name,
        value,
        row_number() over (partition by id, name order by id, value) as rnk
    from yourTable
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
| id  | name | value |
| --- | ---- | ----- |
| 1   | kpi1 | 100   |
| 1   | kpi2 | 0     |
| 2   | kpi1 | 0     |
| 2   | kpi2 | 100   |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, min(value) as value 
from kpi
group by id, name
```